# Short exact sequence to long exact sequence of cohomologies

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $R, S$ be rings with unity and $F : {\mathcal{M}}_R \rightarrow {\mathcal{M}}_S$ be an additive functor. Let
$$
0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{\alpha} B \xrightarrow{\beta} C \rightarrow 0
$$
be a a short exact sequence of right $R$-modules. The question is to construct a long exact sequence of right derived functors (which by definition, are the cohomologies after taking the functor to the injective resolutions)
$$
\dotsc L^n FC \xrightarrow{\delta^n} L^{n+1} FA \xrightarrow{\alpha^{n+1 \ast}} L^{n+1} FB \xrightarrow{\beta^{n+1 \ast}} L^{n+1} FC \xrightarrow{\delta^{n+1}} L^{n+2} FA \rightarrow \dotsc
$$

I am trying to mimic the opposite of "pull back" construction made while dealing with the "projective" version of the same: i.e., a "pushout" may be the right choice

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD} 
 @. 0 @. 0 @. {} @. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @. @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>{}>> A @>{d^{-1}}>> P_0 @>{d^0}>> \dotsc @>{d^{n-3}}>> P_{n-2} @>{d^{n-2}}>> P_{n-1} @>{d^{n-1}}>> P_n @>{d^n}>> \dotsc \\
 {}@V \alpha VV @V f^0 VV @. @V f^{n-2} VV @V f^{n-1} VV \\
0 @>{}>> B @>{{d^{\prime}}^{-1}}>> Q_0 @>{{d^{\prime}}^0}>> \dotsc @>{d^{n-3}}>> Q_{n-2} @>{{d^{\prime}}^{n-2}}>> Q_{n-1}\\
{} @V \beta VV @V g^0 VV @. @V g^{n-2} VV @V g^{n-1} VV \\
0 @>{}>> C @>{{d^{\prime\prime}}^{-1}}>> R_0 @>{{d^{\prime\prime}}^0}>> \dotsc @>{{d^{\prime\prime}}^{n-3}}>> R_{n-2}@>{{d^{\prime\prime}}^{n-2}}>> R_{n-1} \\
@. @VVV @VVV @. @VVV @VVV \\
 @. 0 @. 0 @. {} @. 0 @. 0 \\
\end{CD}

This is easy to build for the $0$-th column. Assuming this is done until $(n-1)$-th stage (all rows and columns exact so far), a necessary requirement is to prove:

${\mathrm{\bf Q.}}$ Show that $\big( {\mathrm{Im}}d^{n-2} \big) f^{n-1} = {\mathrm{Im}}{d^{\prime}}^{n-2}$

This is used to construct the pushout of $P_n$ and ${\mathrm{Im}}{d^{\prime}}^{n-2}$ which embeds in a suitable injective $Q_n$.

I don't see a way to chase the diagram backwards to prove this.

Comment: I found an approach using "Horseshoe lemma" from: http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~vmallick/2013s1/mth622/top_2_02_12.pdf. This approach seems to work except the following point: using $P_0$ injective there is a morphism $\tau^{-1} : B \rightarrow P_0$ so that $\tau^{-1} \circ \alpha = d^{-1}$. One needs to find out why $d^0 \circ \tau^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: Are you sure that $d^{0} \tau ^{-1} =0$? This map is clearly zero when $b \in B$ is in the image of some $A$ under the $\alpha$ map, however it is not always true I think. For instance take the short exact sequence $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then Take the injective resolution $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \mapsto 0$. Then $\alpha = .2$, while $\tau^{-1}$ is the mutliplication by $(1/2)$. Also $d^{0}$ is the projection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. But take $1 \in B =\mathbb{Z}$. Then $d^{0}*(1/2) (1)= [1/2].$

Comment: That is absolutely correct. However if you see the proof of Horseshoe given in above link, the composition of the two consecutive differential at $Q_0$ is zero if and only if $d^0 \circ \tau^{-1} = 0$. I believe a small modification is required.

Comment: The link does not work. However last time I checked the horseshoe lemma we essentially seek a composition $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ which composes to zero. The maps are as follows: $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ first copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ is multiplication by a half, $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ second copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ is inclusion.  We see that going from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (first copy) does not compose to zero while going from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (second copy) doe

Comment: To fix this we seek a map going from $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (second copy) to  $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (first copy) which fixes this error. Take this map to be multiplication by minus a half. Then the composition of the two maps is zero, so you have a chain complex as required.